# Input two numbers and add them when "a" is typed, subtract when "s" is typed

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I'm having a little trouble with this code. When i try to execute I get the message 
    line 12: 0: command not found

---

```
#!/bin/bash

let results=0;

echo "First number please"

read num1

echo "Second mumber"

read num2

echo "Enter operation a=add, s=subtract, m=multiply, and d=divide"

read Op

if [ "$Op" = "a" ]

then

results=$((num1+num2))

elif [ "$Op" = "s" ]

then

results=$((num1-num2))

elif [ "$Op" = "d" ]

then

results=$((num1/num2))

elif [ "$Op" = "m" ]

then

results=$((num1*num2))

fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your shell script to the following code and it works, anyway division by zero bug does still exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

let results=0;
echo "First number please"
read num1
echo "Second number"
read num2
echo "Enter operation a=add, s=subtract, m=multiply, and d=divide"
read Op
if [ "$Op" = "a" ] ; then
    results=`echo "$num1+$num2" |bc `
elif [ "$Op" = "s" ]; then 
    results=`echo "$num1-$num2" |bc `
elif [ "$Op" = "d" ]; then 
    results=`"$num1/$num2" |echo bc`
elif [ "$Op" = "m" ] ; then 
    results=`echo "$num1*$num2"|bc`
else 
    echo "Enter operation a=add, s=subtract, m=multiply, and d=divide"
    read Op
fi;
echo $results
```

Comment: I add and update else section.

Comment: For a Reference use: [Command Line Calculator bc – 11 Extremely Useful Examples](http://mylinuxbook.com/linux-command-line-calculator-bc-examples/)

Answer (score 2):

elif is not a valid keyword as the last else.  Use:

```
If *condition 1*
    #Do Something
elif *condition 2*
    #Do Something Else
else
    #Do this as a last resort
fi
```

An Else If requires an else when not converting to a string as in the bc answer.

Reference: [4 Bash If Statement Examples ( If then fi, If then else fi, If elif else fi, Nested if )](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

I've finished it. I had to remove the `|bc` because it wasn't compatible with the terminal I used for some reason. And I had to put the result line in this format `$(($num1+$num2))` because it wasn't giving me an answer. All it did before was display the inputs, not the arithmetic result. Final code is below:

```
let results=0;
echo "First number please"
read num1 
echo "Second mumber"
read num2
echo "Enter operation a=add, s=subtract, m=multiply, and d=divide"
read Op
if [ "$Op" = "a" ] ; then
    results="$(($num1+$num2))" 
elif [ "$Op" = "s" ]; then
    results="$(($num1-$num2))"
elif [ "$Op" = "d" ]; then
    results="$(($num1/$num2))"
elif [ "$Op" = "m" ] ; then
    results="$(($num1*$num2))"
else
    echo "Enter operation a=add, s=subtract, m=multiply, and d=divide"
    read Op
fi;
echo "$results"
```